# (Microsoft Azure custom vision service: Object Detection) How to find bounding box info of training data?

Tags: object-detection, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I am using Microsoft custom vision service in object detection to extract the wanted objects. And I would like to make a regression test to compare the results. However, I cannot find a place to export the training picture with the bounding box that user defined by GUI.

The model training is done within the custom vision platform provided by Microsoft (https://www.customvision.ai/). Within this platform we can add the images and then tag the objects. I have tried to export the model, but I am not sure where to find the info of training pictures along with their tag(s) and bounding box(es).

I expect that in this platform, user can export the not only the trained model but also the training data (images with tags and bounding boxes.) But I was not able to find them.

Answer (score 4):

All the data that you are looking for is available through `Custom Vision Training API`. Currently the latest API is `v3.0`, its portal is [here](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.0/operations/5c771cdcbf6a2b18a0c3b7fa).

More in details, `GetTaggedImages` method will give you the associations of images and regions bounding box

Sample result of this method with one of my demos:

[image: Demo]

With these details, you will be able to get the image and place the boundingBox that was used for training.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link for [export your model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-your-model). Custom Vision Service exports compact domains. The models generated by compact domains are optimized for the constraints of real-time classification on mobile devices. If the user wants to export the user training data from the custom vision please see the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-delete-data).